# Using __new__ to return the correct subclass, preserving changes made to arguments

Tags: python

```
class FileHandler:
    def __new__(cls, path, *more_args, **kwargs):
        path = do_stuff_to_path(path)
        new_arg = do_more_stuff(path)
        
        if check_format(path) == "video":
            # return VideoHandler(path, new_arg, *more_args, **kwargs)
        elif check_format(path) == "image":
            # return ImageHandler(path, new_arg, *more_args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # just return FileHandler(path, new_arg, *more_args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(path, new_arg, arg1, arg2, kwarg1=None):
        # stuff


class VideoHandler(FileHandler):
    # stuff

class ImageHandler(FileHandler):
    # stuff

FileHandler("path_to_video")  # instance of VideoHandler
FileHandler("path_to_image")  # instance of ImageHandler
```

How do I make A return the right subclass while at the same time preserving the changes I made to the arguments, or passing new arguments? Every existing question about this was either written a decade ago for python 2 or suggests using a factory function, which is not what I want.

Comment: `FileHandler.__new__` isn't really the place to create instances of its subclasses. Unless the subclasses override `__new__`, you are just going to end up running `FileHandler.__new__` again (and again ...).

Comment: Is there no way to stop endless recursion and force instantiation straight to __init__?

Comment: Not easily. You could do something like `return super().__new__(<correct class here>)`, but the automatic call to `__init__` will still receive the *original* arguments, not the modified ones. As a rule of thumb, a superclass should not be responsible for knowing details about any of its subclasses, including which ones even *exist*. You say you don't want to write a factory function, but all you are doing is trying to shoehorn `FileHandler.__new__` into the role of a factory function, for which it isn't suited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than forcing `__new__` to do this, I would define a separate class method for deciding what to do based on the given `path`:

```
class FileHandler:    
    def __init__(self, path, new_arg, arg1, arg2, kwarg1=None):
        # stuff

    @classmethod
    def from_path(cls, path, *args, **kwargs):
        path = do_stuff_to_path(path)
        new_arg = do_more_stuff(path)
        if check_format(path) == "video":
             cls = VideoHandler
        elif check_format(path) == "image":
             cls = ImageHandler
        return cls(path, new_arg, *args, **kwargs)

fh1 = FileHandler.from_path("path_to_video")  # instance of VideoHandler
fh2 = FileHandler.from_path("path_to_image")  # instance of ImageHandler
```

Now when you actually instantiate the object, only the *modified* arguments are passed to `__init__`, since you never actually call the selected type with the original arguments.

Comment: yes, it looks like a much better approach. Factory Method.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the question has been marked as answered, here is a way to do **nearly** what you are looking for.
Except getting a FileHandler instance if no case have been matched.

Here is a basic example for anyone interested, where I didn't use the names defined in the question, because I think that it's now useless.

```
class Foo :
    instantiation = False

    def __new__(cls, *args, mode=None, **kwargs) :
        if Foo.instantiation :
            Foo.instantiation = False
            return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls)

        Foo.instantiation = True
        match mode :
            case '1' :
                return Bar1.__new__(Foo, *args, **kwargs)
            case '2' :
                return Bar2.__new__(Foo, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass #do some stuff
    

############


class Bar1 (Foo) :
    def __new__ (cls, value) :
        return Foo.__new__(Bar1, value)
    
    def __init__(self, value, mode) -> None:
        Foo.__init__(self)
        self.value = value


class Bar2 (Foo) :
    def __new__ (cls, value) :
        return Foo.__new__(Bar2, value)
    
    def __init__(self, value, mode) -> None:
        Foo.__init__(self)
        self.value = value
```

Note that in the code above `mode` is necessarily a keyword argument.
However some modifications are possible to make it both keyword and positional (it will depends on the context where it's used).

---

So now the pros and cons (mostly the cons) of this implementation.

**Pros :**

- Useful for typehinting because `Bar1` and `Bar2` truly derivates from `Foo`.

**Cons :**

- Make your code hard to read (mostly how the instantiation is handled)
- You must keep `mode` in `Bar1.__init__()` and `Bar2.__init__()` even if it's not used
- Make your code slower (approximetly 70% slower)
- Make Foo non-instantiable (I didn't found any way to make it instantiable so I don't think it's possible)

To conclude, it's strange but not impossible.